# Matlab how to show x,y coordinate

Tags: matlab, plot

How to show both x,y coordinate mapped on image?

```
    x = 12;
    y = 54;
    plot(x,y,'+ b'); % this show only the "+" symbol. How to show the both coordinate and the "+"
```

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1dcb46de7a.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?1dcb46de7a.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (might need some adjustment of the coordinates):

```
text(x,y,['(', num2str(x), ', ', num2str(y), ')'])
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code for displaying any data in the form of [x, y, f(x,y)] or data with coordinate
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/72970-display-data-in-form-of-f-x-y-as-map-and-convert-to-matrix

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Generally link only answers are discouraged. Please elaborate a bit and add some context to help those who are facing this problem.